# How to compile gcc toolchain with special sysroot correctly?

Tags: compiling, gcc, glibc, linker, toolchain

I try to compile a new `gcc`, including `binutils` and `glibc`. Since I can not be root, I want to install it all in `~/local`. I set these variables:

```
PREFIX=~/local && export PREFIX
PATH=~/local/bin:$PATH && export PATH
```

I built `binutis`, `gcc` and `glibc` (in exactly this order), with this configuration:

```
../binutils-2.22/configure --prefix=$PREFIX --with-sysroot
../gcc-4.7.3/configure --prefix=$PREFIX
CC='gcc --sysroot=~/local' ../glibc-2.15/configure  --prefix=$PREFIX
```

My idea was that I'd first compile `binutils`, then compile a `gcc` which is linked with the new binutils, and finally, the two compile `glibc` (without need of my system's `glibc` of `/usr/lib`).

However, after `binutils` and `gcc` were compiled and installed correctly, `gcc` fails to compile a simple program while configuring `glibc`:

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

Output (shortened):

```
> gcc --sysroot=~/local/ test.cpp -o test
ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find -lc
ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
```

However, this displays no files:

```
find ~/local -name crti.o
```

Did I configure anything wrong?

My system is a server running a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 ("precise"), but I think it is not system related. The versions of the three toolchain components should fit each other, since openSuSE 12.2 has this combination.

Comment: Once I had almost the same issue except only I had to use the latest `clang` and the latest `glibc`. This post was quite useful for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/184968.

Comment: @skwllsp I think setting the paths or something similar is not going to help, because a `crti.o` is not existing (I've updated this in my post).

Comment: Don't use `~` but `$HOME` in your `PREFIX` and `PATH`, e.g. `export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

You must add `libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes` to the glibc's configure command to avoid configure trying to build and run test programs and choking on that. The problem is that the files `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, `libc.{a,so}` and `crtn.o` are all part of the glibc library that you haven't installed yet.

Learned from Linux From Scratch: [article on glibc](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html)